# Get value with the lowest key value from Map[Int, String]

Tags: scala

Say I have a map: `Map[Int, String]`. How would I get the value `[String]` with the lowest key `[Int]`. I've been trying to implement this functionally, but just can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: if you use a TreeMap, the lowest key will always be first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will get you a value with a lowest key (ignoring some corner cases).

```
def lowestKeyMember[A](m: Map[Int,A]): A = m(m.keys.min)
```

This will break ties arbitrarily and throw on an empty map. If you need to do this operation frequently and/or on large maps, you should look into `SortedMap`.

Answer (score 2):

Maps are not normally sorted. You could however use a SortedMap, then the map will be sorted and the first value will be the head. All you need to do is retrieve the head.

```
map.head()
```

Comment: If you use a sorted map, it's always sorted.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the reminder :). I made the change to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Come on, people!  "Functionally" is code word for "folding".

```
scala> val m = Map(1->"eins",2->"zwei",3->"drei")
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> eins, 2 -> zwei, 3 -> drei)

scala> m.foldLeft(Int.MaxValue -> "") { case (min,p) => if (min._1 <= p._1) min else p }
res0: (Int, String) = (1,eins)
```

But an 8-char operator?

Let's see, is that enough parens?  Don't tell me `->` is like `-` and `/:` is like `/`.

```
scala> (Int.MaxValue -> "" /: m) { case (min,p) => if (min._1 <= p._1) min else p }
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method /: in trait TraversableOnce;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              (Int.MaxValue -> "" /: m) { case (min,p) => if (min._1 <= p._1) min else p }
                                  ^
```

Oh, well, OK.

```
scala> ((Int.MaxValue -> "") /: m) { case (min,p) => if (min._1 <= p._1) min else p }
res2: (Int, String) = (1,eins)
```

Or,

```
scala> import math.Ordering.Implicits._
import math.Ordering.Implicits._

scala> ((Int.MaxValue -> "") /: m) { case (min,p) if min <= p => min case (_, p) => p }
res5: (Int, String) = (1,eins)
```

Answer (score 2):

A variant of the `_.keys.min` solution that works with Options (i.e. will not throw on an empty map):

```
scala> val a : Map[Int, String]=Map(1 -> "1", 2 -> "2")
a: Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2)

scala> val b : Map[Int, String]=Map()
b: Map[Int,String] = Map()

scala> def valueForMinKey[K,V](a : Map[K,V])(implicit cmp : Ordering[K]) = a.keys.reduceOption(cmp.min(_, _)).map(a(_))
valueForMinKey: [K, V](a: Map[K,V])(implicit cmp: Ordering[K])Option[V]

scala> valueForMinKey(a)
res27: Option[String] = Some(1)

scala> valueForMinKey(b)
res28: Option[String] = None
```

In this example, the implicit parameter `cmp` will be satisfied by `Ordering.Int`. The example will work with any Map where the keys can be ordered (and a matching implict can be found by the compiler).